# Create a boolean column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID    DURATION   STATUS   CONSIDER
1     30         ACTIVE   True
2     780        CLOSED   True
3     745        ACTIVE   False
4     366        ACTIVE   False
5     367        ACTIVE   True
```

I would like to create a new column ESTIMATION_FLAG, which is True when DURATION < 700 and STATUS == ACTIVE and CONSIDER == True.

Expected output:

```
ID    DURATION   STATUS   CONSIDER  ESTIMATION_FLAG
1     30         ACTIVE   True      True
2     780        CLOSED   True      False
3     745        ACTIVE   False     False
4     366        ACTIVE   False     False
5     367        ACTIVE   True      True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for masks and chain by `&` for bitwise `AND`, advantage is less `()`:

```
df['ESTIMATION_FLAG'] = df['DURATION'].lt(700) & df['STATUS'].eq('ACTIVE') & df['CONSIDER']
print (df)
   ID  DURATION  STATUS  CONSIDER  ESTIMATION_FLAG
0   1        30  ACTIVE      True             True
1   2       780  CLOSED      True            False
2   3       745  ACTIVE     False            False
3   4       366  ACTIVE     False            False
4   5       367  ACTIVE      True             True
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
df["ESTIMATION_FLAG"] = (df["DURATION"] < 700) & (df["STATUS"]=="ACTIVE") & (df["CONSIDER"]==True)
```